# glb import error

Tags: import

I am trying to import a glb file exported from 3ds max using verge3d but getting a list of errors. 
Will appreciate any direction to solve this.
Thanks!

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 758, in execute
    return self.import_gltf2(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 779, in import_gltf2
    BlenderGlTF.create(self.gltf_importer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_gltf.py", line 41, in create
    BlenderScene.create(gltf, scene_idx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_scene.py", line 80, in create
    BlenderNode.create(gltf, node_idx, None)  # None => No parent
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 169, in create
    BlenderNode.create(gltf, child_idx, node_idx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 63, in create
    mesh = BlenderMesh.create(gltf, pynode.mesh, node_idx, parent)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_mesh.py", line 58, in create
    BlenderMaterial.create(gltf, prim.material, vertex_color)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_material.py", line 89, in create
    BlenderEmissiveMap.create(gltf, material_idx, vertex_color, factor_only=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_map_emissive.py", line 31, in create
    BlenderEmissiveMap.create_nodetree(gltf, material_idx, vertex_color, factor_only)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_map_emissive.py", line 49, in create_nodetree
    principled = get_preoutput_node_output(node_tree)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\com\gltf2_blender_material_helpers.py", line 40, in get_preoutput_node_output
    output_node = get_output_node(node_tree)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\com\gltf2_blender_material_helpers.py", line 18, in get_output_node
    output = [node for node in node_tree.nodes if node.type == 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL'][0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the importer add-on crashes due to some incompatibility with Verge3D-exported asset. You might want to file a bug report on the addon's GitHub page:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues